# Линейно конгруэнтный генератор (Вычисление мощности)

Tags: c

Требуется подобрать параметры для лкг для машинного слова 64 бита. Взял те, что предложила википедия (a = 6364136223846793005; b = 1442695040888963407). Требуется также найти его характеристики, но с мощностью полученного генератора как-то не получается. Формула для нахождения мощности (как я нашел) - ((a - 1)^s) mod m = 0 ,где минимальное s - и есть мощность. Решил попробовать графиками (поскольку все никак не смог найти альтернативу) и вбил в дезмос формулу. И получилось это:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это трактовать? Может быть я что-то упустил или ошибку сделал.

Comment: `s` -  целое. Вы строите график для вещественных `s`. Он бесполезен.

Comment: [Вот тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4#%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) приведены три свойства, который вы можете проверить и убедится что они выполняются. Следовательно период есть 2^64.